# Why won't UITableCell immediately deselect when opening a URL in Safari?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an app that closes and goes to Safari to open a URL when a `UITableViewCell` is touched. When I go back to the app though, the cell is still selected for a few seconds. Why doesn't it deselect immediately? Is it a bug? Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]];
    }

}
```

I tried moving `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];` to the top and turning off animation, but it didn't help. It's not that big of a deal, but I would like it to deselect immediately if possible.

This happens with `UIButton` too. It remains in the highlighted state for a second or two after returning to the app.

Comment: can you post more code please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes like `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];` take effect at the next iteration through the run loop. When you exit via `openURL:` that delays the next iteration until you've switched back into the app. Switching back is achieved by cycling in an image of the screen before you left then a few moments later making the app interactive again. Hence the selected image persists.

Putting the specifics of the implementation aside, the logic is that things that affect screen content are bundled together and made atomic so that when you're doing view adjustments you don't constantly have to think 'oh no, what if the frame redraws now and only the changes up to here are done?'. Per the iOS multitasking model, that atomic unit of adjusting the interface doesn't occur until you're back in the app.

Quick fix:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // deselect right here, right now
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                    performSelector:@selector(openURL:)
                    withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]
                    afterDelay:0.0];

        /*
              performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: schedules a particular
              operation to happen in the future. A delay of 0.0 means that it'll
              be added to the run loop's list to occur as soon as possible.

              However, it'll occur after any currently scheduled UI updates
              (such as the net effect of a deselectRowAtIndexPath:...)
              because that stuff is already in the queue.
        */
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, that's really an insightful explanation and a great solution. Thank you!